# Why is my UITableViewCell indicating a null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get a UITableViewCell to use to change its title and contents. However, I'm having trouble getting the tableViewCell because when I call the following method

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

inside of this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ // 3
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Flickr Photo Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; // Why is cell NULL?
    if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

I can see in the debugger after setting a breakpoint that the value is (null):

[image: Cell Identifier]

And in my storyboard I set the cell identifier to be `Flickr Photo Cell`

Comment: Yeah, the cell can be nil if there's no cell to dequeue.

Comment: The problem is that the cell is not nil. The cell is (null). I included a check for nil after the code which I will now update to reflect this

Comment: `nil`, `Nil`, `NULL`, and `0` are the same thing in Objective C; it's just that each is conventionally used for a different data type.

Comment: @Austin But then why is the check for nil not working?

Comment: @jacks4jokers Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding... Is the `if(cell == nil){` block executing when your cell == NULL?

Comment: I'm not sure. I checked and the block is not executing. I also checked with (!cell) and the block wouldn't execute

Comment: And Austin's right `nil`, `Nil`, `NULL`, and `0`, are the same thing. I was simply thinking about the conventions, e.g nil is used for object pointers, etc.

Comment: Because `dequeueCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` doh

Comment: If you set your breakpoint on the line `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, then that line has not yet been executed, and the `cell` variable has nothing assigned to it. The debugger may have chosen to to print out an uninitialized variable as "(null)".

Comment: I believe that `dequeueCellWithIdentifer` automatically uses the indexPath passed into the tableView method.

Comment: I have set breakpoints after the value and set if statements that should have been executed the value is still null after the instantiation, or rather as it seems, indicated as null by the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register a nib or cell class with that identifier before attempting to dequeue the cell? Registration is usually done in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NameOfFlickrPhotoCellNib" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Flickr Photo Cell"];
}
```

Comment: I'm using a storyboard. I'm not using nib files. I set in IB my cell Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

you can create you cell by code:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ // 3
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Flickr Photo Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
// Why is cell NULL?
if(!cell){
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
//here configure you cel..Be carefully this cell doen't anything of you storyboard cell.
NSLog(@"Cell is not nil:%@",[cell description]);
return cell;
}
```

or using Storyboard (or xib)

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseINSTORYBOARD" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```